# Split single line into multiple lines, Newline character missing for all the lines in input file

Tags: linux, text-processing, newlines, split

I there a way to split single line into multiple lines with 3 columns.
New line characters are missing at the end of all the lines in the file.

I tried using awk, but it is splitting each column as one row instead of 3 columns in each row.

```
awk '{ gsub(",", "\n") } 6' filename
```

where `filename`'s content looks like:

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O
```

Desired output has 3 columns in each line:

```
A,B,C
D,E,F
G,H,I
J,K,L
M,N,O
```

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: Looks like a job for `rs` (the "reshape" command).  `rs -c, -C, 0 3  <<<'A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O'` has you most of the way there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Using `awk`

```
$ awk -v RS='[,\n]' '{a=$0;getline b; getline c; print a,b,c}' OFS=, filename
A,B,C
D,E,F
G,H,I
J,K,L
M,N,O
```

#### How it works

- `-v RS='[,\n]'`

  This tells awk to use any occurrence of either a comma or a newline as a record separator.
- `a=$0; getline b; getline c`

  This tells awk to save the current line in variable `a`, the next line in varaible `b`, and the next line after that in variable `c`.
- `print a,b,c`

  This tells awk to print `a`, `b`, and `c`
- `OFS=,`

  This tells awk to use a comma as the field separator on output.

## Using `tr` and `paste`

```
$ tr , '\n' <filename | paste -d, - - -
A,B,C
D,E,F
G,H,I
J,K,L
M,N,O
```

#### How it works

- `tr , '\n' <filename`

  This reads from filename while converting all commas to newlines.
- `paste -d, - - -`

  This `paste` to read three lines from stdin (one for each `-`) and paste them together, each separated by a comma (`-d,`).

## Alternate awk

```
$ awk -v RS='[,\n]' '{printf "%s%s",$0,(NR%3?",":"\n")}' filename
A,B,C
D,E,F
G,H,I
J,K,L
M,N,O
```

#### How it works

- `-v RS='[,\n]'`

  This tells awk to use any occurrence of either a comma or a newline as a record separator.
- `printf "%s%s",$0,(NR%3?",":"\n")`

  This tells awk to print the current line followed by either a comma or a newline depending the value of the current line number, `NR`, modulo 3.

Comment: Thank you for quick response.. Yes,, Its working fine. :)

Answer (score 5):

```
sed 's/\(\([^,]\+,\)\{3\}\)/\1\n/g;s/,\n/\n/g' filename
```

I know that you asked for an `awk` solution, and I'll now try to submit that as an edit to this answer, but for me a `sed` solution was simpler... ... and user john1024 beat me to it, with a fine `awk` solution. See there. His `paste` and `tr` solution is probably the most proper classic unix-ish answer.

1. This solution uses the extended regex features of GNU sed.
2. `\(..\)` is  a regex collection group. Note that the solution uses two, one nested within the other.
3. `[^,]+,` is any string that doesn't have a comma, followed by a comma. In your case, a column or field.
4. `\{3\}` is a regex multiplier, indicating to use the prior regex expression three times.
5. `\1` is a regex back-reference. to the prior regex.
6. `g` means do it for all instances on the line.
7. `s/,\n/\n/g` removes the trailing comma. It's necessary to include the newline character here, because `sed` is still considering the input as a single line.

Comment: I had the original version inadequately indented so some of the backslashes did not appear in the markdown output.

Comment: @RakeshK You're quite welcome.

Comment: This reminds me of https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/